# How to Install Yii2 Code standard in Yii2 Project?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

> $ ./vendor/bin/phpcs backend/controllers/AdvertisementController.php
>   --colors

```
ERROR: the "Yii" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend

 "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards": "2.*"
    }
```

> Next, create a phpcs.xml.dist file on the project root directory, see
>   PHP_CodeSniffer Documentation: Using a Default Configuration File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Yii2 App Basic Standard">
    <description>Yii2 App Basic coding standard</description>

    <exclude-pattern>/runtime/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/web/assets/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/vendor/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/requirements.php</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref="vendor/yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards/Yii2"/>

    <rule ref="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace">
        <exclude-pattern>/migrations/*</exclude-pattern>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName.NotCamelCaps">
        <exclude-pattern>/migrations/*</exclude-pattern>
    </rule>
</ruleset>



$ ./vendor/bin/phpcs backend/controllers/AdvertisementController.php --colors
```

> ERROR: the "Yii" coding standard is not installed. The installed
>   coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend

```
 "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards": "2.*"
    }
```

Next, create a `phpcs.xml.dist` file on the project root directory, see `PHP_CodeSniffer` Documentation: Using a Default Configuration File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Yii2 App Basic Standard">
    <description>Yii2 App Basic coding standard</description>

    <exclude-pattern>/runtime/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/web/assets/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/vendor/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/requirements.php</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref="vendor/yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards/Yii2"/>

    <rule ref="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace">
        <exclude-pattern>/migrations/*</exclude-pattern>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="Squiz.Classes.ValidClassName.NotCamelCaps">
        <exclude-pattern>/migrations/*</exclude-pattern>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

> Last, use command:

```
php composer.phar install --dev
vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php .
```

> This thrown me error vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8
>   --extensions=php .

```
 coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are
 MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend
```

**How i can install Yii2 as coding standard**

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Bro please see this

Comment: why are you using this extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the extension, you are trying to install you should know the purpose **why** it should be used and **when**.

**From The [Yii 2 Core Framework Code Style](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md)**

> The following code style is used for Yii 2.x core and official
> extensions development. If you want to pull-request code into the
> core, consider using it.
>
> We aren't forcing you to use this code style for your application.
> Feel free to choose what suits you better.

#### When To Use

It is only used when you are developing `Yii2` not working **WITH** Yii2 means only if you are going to contribute to the core functionality of the framework then use this extension

#### When to Ignore

If you are working on a project which is **using** Yii2 framework, you don't need to install this extension as the PHPCS can directly work in this case if you have it installed, all the standards that are used already are in PHPCS are not much different,

You dont need this extension, leave it, PHPCS can do the work directly.

Comment: PHPCS need code stand to run in my project.If i use PEAR,PSR-1 or PSR-2,Zend  It ask me for tags for file name and class name.So i have done it by installin Yii2 code standard and test the error using thers command     vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php backend --colors added php.xml.dist file in root

Comment: @Sajid have you read my answer? i told you already you dont need it , neither PHPCS requires you to install the Yii2 Code standard.